# How to configure SonarCloud

Tags: java, encryption, sonarqube, travis-ci, sonarcloud

I have java project and I want to integrate it with SonarCloud I Follow the official steps:

> Inspecting code with the SonarQube Scanner #
>
> Before inspecting your code, you need to:
>
> 1. Create a user authentication token for your account on SonarCloud.
> 2. Encrypt this token travis encrypt abcdef0123456789 or define SONAR_TOKEN in your Repository Settings
> 3. Find which SonarCloud.io organization you want to push your project on and get its key
> 4. Create a sonar-project.properties file for your project (see the documentation). Then add the following lines to your .travis.yml file
>      to trigger the analysis:

add in my travis.yml file

```
 addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "xelian-github"
    token:
      secure: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
    branches:
      - master
script:
  # other script steps might be done before running the actual analysis
  - sonar-scanner
```

Where SONAR_TOKEN is a variable on Travis CI pointing to the key from SonarCloud.(It is not encrypted).
[image]
From SonarCloud I add permissions
[image]

But when I start the travis build I have the following error:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export SONAR_TOKEN=[secure]

 ....
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

It seems to me that I the travis do not have permissions to upload results to SonarCloud. Is the problem in the token or in some Sonar configurations.

Comment: What is the "official documentation" you're talking about? If you look at http://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/, you'll find the right path for Maven projects, and it does not mention using "sonar-project.properties" at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official entry point to configure a project on SonarCloud is the ["Get Started" page](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/getting-started/overview/):

- You will see that for Maven projects, you **don't need** to create a `sonar-project.properties` file at all
- You will even find a link to a [sample Maven project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_java-maven-travis) that is analyzed on SonarCloud

Comment: Hello Fabrice, there's a related issue some users are getting with the Maven execution.

More about this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/50012220/2073804
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7814
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7182

Comment: See my answer on your post: you are doing something wrong, everything is working correctly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find a solution. In the root path whete the yml file is you have to add:

**sonar-project.properties**

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=java-sonar-runner-simple:master
sonar.projectName=Rss-service
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=/microservice-application/rss-reader-service/src/main/java
sonar.java.binaries=/microservice-application/rss-reader-service/target/classes

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

And in the travis.yml I add:
script:

```
  # other script steps might be done before running the actual analysis
  - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar
```

**Edit**:

sonar-project.properties not necessary. Only maven goals make sense.

Comment: This is definitely NOT the right way to do this for Maven projects. Please see my answer to this question.

Comment: Haha that explains why all my properties from this file were ignored.

Comment: I personally use gradle a I have a ignored file `sonar-project.properties`, I manually import values within gradle plugin.

Comment: +1 for being the first place I could find an example of the configuration file (despite combing the sonarcloud docs)